# Nginx redirects to https://web

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

My webapp was working fine until today, when my domain stopped working. I was using example.com:8000/ to reach my Django app, but now it redirects me to https://web/. I've tried to go back to previous commits, but the issue does not disappear.

My nginx.conf looks like:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {

  location /static/ {
          autoindex on;
          alias /static/;
      }
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;
}
```

docker-compose.yaml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ng01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
      - ./code/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dg01
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn fortex.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./static:/static
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: ps01
    volumes:
      - pg_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pg_volume: {}
```

Nginx redirects without logging, but when I use incognito in chrome it logs normally but still redirects me.

Comment: If it was a 301 redirect then might be cached in the browser's cache so try a different browser and see if it redirects there.

Comment: Worked with firefox, thank you!